# MYSQL как использовать строку в конструкции IN (string)

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть элементы,которые пользователь добавил в избранное.
С JS на сервер идет JSON id этих элементов. PHP  заносит их в БД в виде 12, 25, 35, ... Как сделать чтобы при выборке SQL использовал их все, а не только первый элемент. В документации у них не могу найти ответ. Либо делать два запроса, либо менять структуру??? Подскажите как выйти из данной ситуации.

Пример запроса:

```
SELECT l.`id`,l.`name`, cc.`img`
FROM `list` l
JOIN content_list cl ON l.`content_id` = cl.`id`
WHERE l.id IN (SELECT f.selected
               FROM favorites f
               WHERE f.user_id = 1);
```

Comment: IN ( ' . implode(',', $arrayWithIds) . ') если я правильно понял

Comment: Поподробнее можно,  как я понял Вы написали для PHP.  У меня проблема не в том чтобы в БД занести строку, а считать ее в подзапросе и использовать в основном как список id  элементов. Когда в запрос просто вставляю этот список, то отрабатывает, а когда этот список получен через подзапрос,  то берется только 1 id, а последующие откидываются.

Comment: запрос то написан правильно, вы уверены, что подзапрос в скобках выдает несколько записей?

Comment: В том то и дело, что подзапрос выдает 1 запись - так и задумывалось, т.е. есть 1 запись на пользователя  с строкой, содержащей id  выбранных пунктов. Вот я и ломаю голову возможно так делать, или он только отрабатывает если каждый id будет в отдельной записи. А так запросы отрабатывают штатно. Мне хочется понять можно такие монипуляции производить или нет. Если нет переделаю с 2 запросами из PHP. Просто с 1 запросом проще его обслужить: кэш и т.п.

Comment: Нет. Через IN так не получится. А что мешает сделать отдельную таблицу, привязанную к user_id и по одному индексу на строку?

Comment: Используйте функцию FIELD_IN_SET().

Comment: Akina, от всей Души благодарю, функция FIELD_IN_SET() - это то что доктор  прописал (Прошу выложить ваш ответ не как комментарий, чтобы я мог его отметить как решение проблемы).   Dmitry Kozlov Вам тоже большая признательность за проявленное внимание и помощь, и да список id  мне хочется хранить одной строкой, на это завязана работа как JS,так и PHP скриптов

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию FIELD_IN_SET()